# Standard page layout line break

Tags: page-layout

I'm not sure if this is even possible in a standard page layout, I have `Long Text Area(32768)` on a custom field `Message__c` so the data I have is with line break as shown below and I have tried `\n` but I'm getting everything in one line.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
This is a line one 
this is a line two 
this is a line three 
Last line
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I have understood your question correctly.

I am updating Case Description field (which is `LongTextArea(32000)`) from Developer console like this:

```
Case obj = [SELECT Description FROM Case WHERE Id = '500q0000006XBEP'];
obj.Description = 'First Line' + '\n\r' + 'Second Line' + '\n\r' + 'Third Line';
update obj;
```

And it is showing in UI:

[image: Case description]

If I print that in debug log:

```
Case obj = [SELECT Description FROM Case WHERE Id = '500q0000006XBEP'];
System.debug('description=' + obj.Description);
```

It gives me:

[image: case desc debug]

**Update based on comments:**

If you just press ENTER button to put in new line like this:

[image: case desc1]

That will give me results:

[image: case desc 2]

**2nd Update from Comments:**

if you are receiving text like this

```
This is a line one <br> this is a line two <br> this is a line three <br>Last line
```

> Then just replace `<br>` with `\n\r` before assigning that into the field and it will work.

```
Case obj = [SELECT Description FROM Case WHERE Id = '500q0000006XBEP'];
String str = 'This is a line one <br> this is a line two <br> this is a line three <br>Last line';
obj.Description = str.replace('<br>','\n\r');
update obj;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55488/discussion-on-answer-by-santanu-boral-standard-page-layout-line-break).